# Experiencing a data binding issue on a Blazor .NET 8 Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

```
@page "/login"
@using BlazorWebAppNew.Data
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@inject UserDataContext dataContext



<PageTitle>Login</PageTitle>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h6 class="card-title">Please log in</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <EditForm Model="@loginModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleLogin" FormName="LoginForm">
                        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                        <ValidationSummary />
                        <div class="form-group mb-2">
                            <label for="email">Email:</label>
                            <InputText id="email" @bind-Value="loginModel.Email"></InputText>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group mb-2">
                            <label for="password">Password:</label>
                            <InputText id="password" type="password" @bind-Value="loginModel.Password"></InputText>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                    </EditForm>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel();

    private async Task HandleLogin()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Email: {loginModel.Email}, Password: {loginModel.Password}");
        var user = await dataContext.Users
           .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == loginModel.Email && u.Password == loginModel.Password);


        Console.WriteLine($"User found: {user != null}");

        if (user != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Entering if block - Login successful");
            // Additional logic for successful login
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Entering else block - Login failed");
            // Logic for failed login
        }
    }

    public class LoginModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Hi, I've been trying to get this to work for the past couple of days.

I just want to create a basic login page with the user's credentials in my local SQL server. Whenever I bruteforce the user's information into .FirstOrDefaultAsync , it works (i replace loginModel.email and loginModel.password with a string containing that information).

However, whenever I try to make it work via the login form, it always indicates:

User found: False
Entering else block - Login failed

I can't seem to understand why, your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can't specify the `id` in your inputs

Comment: The data binding is working, so it's probably an issue with your database setup. Example fiddle: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/vnrnly1z

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly, pretty sure the database is connected to the application as my code works fine when i brute force the Model data 

`var user = await dataContext.Users
           .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == "test@gmail.com" && u.Password == "123";`

This only works for the right data in my database.

I removed the id in my inputs and i'm still encountering the same issue. I added the following to the top of my code and it doesn't update either

`<p>
    Email: @loginModel.Email
    <br />
    Password: @loginModel.Password
</p>`
Apologies, i'm new

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with `async Task [...] await` but since I'm accessing a local database, i don't think removing the asynchronous nature is a good idea

appsettings.json

`"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Host=localhost;Database=postgres;Username=postgres;Password=123"
}
`
Program.cs

`var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<UserDataContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));`

Comment: "await dataContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync" is retuning a null.  The response suggests the query is actually running - you don't get an exception, so `u => u.Email == loginModel.Email && u.Password == loginModel.Password` doesn't get a match from the database.  You need to check things like case and spaces in the database fields.

Answer (score -1):

Your model property is `private` and not accessible to your .razor component.

This should work:

```
@code {
    protected LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel();
    ...
```

If you change `loginModel.Email` to `@loginModel.Email` then the following markup will not compile, because `loginModel` is not accessible.  Your original markup compiled `loginModel.Email` as a string, but this was incorrect for data binding to the `Email` property.

```
 <div class="form-group mb-2">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    @* Note the @ symbol before loginModel.Email *@
    <InputText id="email" @bind-Value="@loginModel.Email"></InputText>
 </div>
```

Comment: Private properties are accessible to the razor. The fiddle I posted as a comment on the OP demonstrates this. https://blazorfiddle.com/s/vnrnly1z

Comment: Aha, thanks for the correction @KurtHamilton!  I was testing with an example that has the C# code in a separate file (ie, .razor.cs) and the private access would not work in that case.

Comment: No problem. In that case then you would of course have a very good point.